# How can I increase the maximum volume output by VLC?

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player

I like watching movies (using VLC) on my laptop and sometimes the volume is too low for my taste even when the volume in VLC is set to the maximum of 125% on the volume control (bottom right):

[image] [image]

I already have all the volumes set to 100% in the Windows Volume Mixer:

[image]

What are my options to increase the volume beyond this maximum?

Comment: I believe there was an option to increase the maximum to 200% somewhere. However, you cannot defeat physics: If the waveform (at the DAC) gets over 100%, you’ll get distortions.

Comment: yes, mouse scrolling in the VLC window should allow to adjust the volume beyond 100%. I'm trying to find where the setting to show this info in the media bar (so you can adjust it there too, to higher than 100% but right now I can only find instructions referring to changing it in Qt, which may or may not apply to the windows version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### How can I increase the maximum volume output by VLC?

There are a couple of options.

**Modify the "Audio gain" setting:**

> 1. Press Ctrl+P or Select Tools → Preferences.
> 2. Select 'All' radio button under Show settings at the bottom of the preferences window.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Next select Audio.
>
> In the right side of preference window, you would see the Audio gain
> set to 1.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. The Audio gain can be increased up to 8. Set a value according to your needs. The more you set the more will be the volume.
> 5. Click Save.
> 6. Press Save and close VLC.
> 7. Restart VLC.

Source [How to Increase the Volume of any Media file using VLC](https://syncwithtech.blogspot.com/2014/06/increase-sound-using-vlc.html)

**Change the Maximum Volume Displayed setting**

> 1. Press Ctrl+P or Select Tools → Preferences.
> 2. Select 'All' radio button under Show settings at the bottom of the preferences window.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Expand the Interface tree and
> 4. Expand Main interfaces.
> 5. Select Qt and change the default value of Maximum Volume displayed from 125 to 200 or 300 (300 is the maximum)
>
> [image]
>
> 6. Click Save.
> 7. Press Save and close VLC.
> 8. Restart VLC.
>
> [image] [image]

Source [How to Increase VLC Volume up to 800% - Geekswipe](https://geekswipe.net/technology/computing/increase-vlc-volume-800/)

Comment: none of the above options work with the bluetooth headphones. I tried both and no effect

Comment: @Suncatcher Works with my Bluetooth headphones.

Answer (score 5):

As per your image in VLC, you should be able to set the volume higher, and infact it can go as high as 400%, but this isn't indicated in the graphical options. Simply clicking within the volume bar to the required volume, or 'mouse scrolling' on the video's window should cause the volume to inrease/decrease, beyond 100% as seen here: [image]

If you wish to control the volume in the UI, and go higher than 125% then you can do so by changing the setting in the Qt menu in preferences:

[image]

Comment: Clicking in the Volume Bar doesn't work (max 125%). See the second part of my answer to fix this.

Comment: Hehe. You answered first while I was preparing my self answer ... and then edited yours to include what I already said in mine ...