# VLC Audio Won't Increase Beyond 100

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

I have windows 10 version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1415).
I have VLC version 3.0.15

In VLC:
I set the audio gain to 8.
I set the interface to show audio maximum as 300 instead of default 100.

**The problem is that the volume won't increase past 100.**

I tried changing all the settings that I can think of that is related to audio with no luck.

I tried suggestions in a similar (not identical) post in SO with no luck too.

Comment: have you verified that you did not activate a option like normalize in the advanced settings?

Comment: Did you restart VLC? [It works for me](https://superuser.com/a/1513291)

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, and I restarted the PC. and I even reinstalled VLC. It is a long-time problem.

Comment: @djdomi I could not find an option to disable normalization. it is just two values and I tried many combinations of them with no luck. They are the number of buffers and max volume level.

Comment: its inside the sounds settings, these are in the same panel where the windows sounds can be changed, activated or getting disabled

Comment: @djdomi the "Normalize volume to" option is disabled already.

Comment: well, then uninstall, reboot and retry to install vlc

Comment: @djdomi I did it a lot of changes to settings overtime to get the best of VLC. Is there a way to save those changes so I can redo them manually later?

Comment: maybe these changes are the issue, you have to either Screenshot them or maybe try to find the corresponding reg keys

Comment: @djdomi I guess so, this is why I want to redo them manually one by one. Unfortunately, it seems that there is no way to save the settings from the GUI. Anyhow, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: On Windows the settings are stored in %APPDATA%\vlc directory so you can backup the whole folder with its subfolders and restore it if needed.
vlcrc contains the main program settings and vlc-qt-interface.ini the interface settings. give that a shot